# Proving a set is closed but not open

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Suppose we have that set $S = \{ (x,y) \in R^2 : x>0, y = \sin(1/x)
>  \}$. Prove that $S$ is closed but not open.

${\bf Relevant \; definitions:}$ A set $S$ is open if for every $s \in S$, one can find an $r>0$ so that $|x-s| < r$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. $S$ is closed if $S^c$ is open.

### Attempt:

Now, the problem here is to make an $r>0$ so that the ball $B(r,x)$ is in the complement of $S$ for all $x \in S^c$. (here x =(x,y))  Now, if $x \in S^c$, then $x < 0$ and $y \neq \sin (1/x)$. Here is where I get stuck. I dont know how to construct such an $r$. Any help?

Comment: What about at $(x=0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$? Can you construct such a ball?

Comment: no because there can be found some (x',y') where ball intersects sin(1/x)

Comment: I think this is wrong. $(0,0)$ is a counterexample. Any ball contains a point in $S$ in $x$-axis at least.

Comment: In general, once you see strict inequality in a set "closed" is probably not true (unless one considers unbounded constructs or something similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\frac 1 {n\pi},0) \in S$ for each $n$ and $(\frac 1 {n\pi},0) \to (0,0)$ so the set is not closed. It is not open either. $(1,\sin\, 1)$ is in $S$ but there is no $r>0$ such that $B((1,\sin\, 1),r) \subset S$?: if there is such an $r$ we get a contradiction as follows: let $0<|y-\sin (1)| <r$. Then $(1,y) \in B((1,\sin\, 1),r)$ but $(1,\sin (1))$ is not in $S$. (If it is in $S$ then we must have $y =\sin(1)$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, using this definition is easy. The challenge here is to use first principles.

Comment: @JimmySabater In your attempt you are trying to prove that $S^{c}$ is open. This is not true. First principles or otherwise you cannot prove  a wrong statement. I have shown you why $S^{c}$ is not open.

Comment: Kavi.Kindly elaborate on your last line: B( (1, sin 1), r), r >0, not a subset of S, I do not get it. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSzilas I have given the details now.

Comment: Kavi.Thank you.